# How can Fill In Mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapper

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {   

       String line = value.toString();     
       int left = line.indexOf("{");
       int right = line.indexOf("}");
       String subMyString = line.substring(left+1, right);  

          for (String myWord : subMyString.split("\\W+")) {    
          if (myWord.length() > 0)        
              context.write(new Text(myWord), new IntWritable(1));       
          }
}
```

In my mapper.class

And my input file:

```
...

...bla..bla..{asd assda sddsaasd asd}

...bla..bla..{asd assda sddsaasd asd}

...bla..bla..{asd assda sddsaasd asd}

...
```

Naturally: `line= ...bla..bla..{asd assda sddsaasd asd}`
In All line are includes "{" and "}" characters. I want fill in contex in between these characters. But I am getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` during compilation.

How should I change my code?  Why am I getting error?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe every line doesn't have `{` and `}`?  Why don't you do a sanity check and see if `left` or `right` == `-1`?

Comment: Every line have { and } , ı tested with log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you have provided with, there are two ways you can get an `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

1. The `{` and `}` are not balanced in the input you are running on.
2. The case where there are no `{` and `}`in the value isn't handled. Because, if they are not present in the value, the `left` and `right` variables become `-1`. And therefore you get an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

So, the code you should change is something like this:

```
  //......
   int left = line.indexOf("{");
   int right = line.indexOf("}");

    if(left > 0 && right > 0){
      String subMyString = line.substring(left+1, right);  
      for (String myWord : subMyString.split("\\W+")) {    
      if (myWord.length() > 0)        
          context.write(new Text(myWord), new IntWritable(1));       
      }
     }
   //..........
```